# Don't have idea why those errors appears

Tags: python

Everything in this code looks right to me, but when i put some numbers that length is different than 2 or put a word, at the end of code an error appear right below "Good bye"

How do i fix that?

Thank you in advance.

Code:

```
def main():
    def inputnumber(message):
        while True:
            try:
                inputnumber = int(input(message))
            except ValueError:
                print("No,no,no! Put a valid number!\n")
                continue
            if len(str(inputnumber)) < 2:
                print("Hey! That\'s too short! Please, type a two digit number.\n")
                return main()
            elif len(str(inputnumber)) > 2:
                print("Hey! That\'s too long! Please, type a two digit number.\n")
                return main()
            else:
                return inputnumber
                break

    def yes_no(message):
        userinput = str(input(message)).lower()
        if userinput == "yes" :
            return 1
        elif userinput == "no" :
            return 0
        else:
            return yes_no("Please, use 'yes' or 'no'.")


    number = str(inputnumber("Type a two digit number: "))
    total = int(number[0]) + int(number[1])
    print(f"{total}\n")

    answer = yes_no("Do you want to try again?\n")
    if answer == 1:
        print("Okay! Don\'t forget the rules!\n")
        main()
    elif answer == 0:
        print("Good bye!")
main()
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: This works perfectly fine on my machine, could you tell us what the error is?

Comment: Don't use recursion in place of looping.

Comment: There's no point in having `break` after `return inputnumber`. Nothing executes after a return statement.

Comment: Not sure if this is your error, but your `inputnumber` function uses recursion inside of a `while` loop that should already do the job.  Just `continue` instead of doing `return main()`.

Comment: `return main()` means that `inputnumber()` will return what `main()` returns. But `main()` has no `return` statement.

Comment: These Errors :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\T-Gamer\PycharmProjects\guppe\ztm.py", line 38, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:\Users\T-Gamer\PycharmProjects\guppe\ztm.py", line 29, in main
    total = int(number[0]) + int(number[1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'N'

Comment: You're getting that error because `inputnumber` returned `None`.  `str(None)` becomes the string `"None"`, and on the next line you're trying to add the first and second characters of that -- `total = int("N") + int("o")`, which is what produces the `ValueError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `inputnumber` function doesn't always return two digits (sometimes it returns `None`).  Since it already runs everything in a `while True` loop, when the user enters the wrong input you should use this loop to re-prompt rather than starting over by calling `main()` (which will return `None`).

In general, your program should be using `while` loops consistently when it needs to potentially do something more than once.  There are other opportunities for simplification -- for example, there's no point in having `inputnumber` convert the input to an `int` if the caller is immediately going to convert it back to a `str`.

```
def main() -> None:
    def inputnumber() -> str:
        while True:
            inputnumber = input("Type a two digit number: ")
            if not inputnumber.isdigit():
                print("No,no,no! Put a valid number!\n")
            elif len(inputnumber) < 2:
                print("Hey! That\'s too short! Please, type a two digit number.\n")
            elif len(inputnumber) > 2:
                print("Hey! That\'s too long! Please, type a two digit number.\n")
            else:
                return inputnumber

    def yes_no(message: str) -> bool:
        while True:
            userinput = input(message).lower()
            if userinput == "yes":
                return True
            elif userinput == "no":
                return False
            else:
                print("Please, use 'yes' or 'no'.")

    while True:
        number = inputnumber()
        total = int(number[0]) + int(number[1])
        print(f"{total}\n")

        if yes_no("Do you want to try again?\n"):
            print("Okay! Don\'t forget the rules!\n")
        else:
            print("Good bye!")
            return


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to `return main()` in `inputnumber()`. `main()` doesn't return anything, so `inputnumber()` is returning `None` in that case. The string `"None"` is then assigned to `number`, and then it tries to do

```
total = int(number[0]) + int(number[1])
```

`number[0]` is `N`, `number[1]` is `o`, so those `int()` calls will fail because they're not numbers.

`inputnumber()` should not call `main()` when the user enters the wrong length. It should just let the `while` loop repeat.

```
    def inputnumber(message):
        while True:
            try:
                inputnumber = int(input(message))
            except ValueError:
                print("No,no,no! Put a valid number!\n")
                continue
            if len(str(inputnumber)) < 2:
                print("Hey! That\'s too short! Please, type a two digit number.\n")
            elif len(str(inputnumber)) > 2:
                print("Hey! That\'s too long! Please, type a two digit number.\n")
            else:
                return inputnumber
```

Also, instead of converting the number to a string and checking its length, you can use `if inputnumber < 10:` and `if inputnumber > 99:`